# Python for everybody assignment 3.3

Tags: python

Why wouldn't my for loop work? If I put in 0.85 for grade score it'd print out F and error message instead of B. Why is this?

```
grade=input('Score Grade:')
fg=float(grade)
for fg in range(0,1):
    if fg >= 0.9:
        print('A')
    elif fg>=0.8:
        print('B')
    elif fg>=0.7:
        print('C')
    elif fg>=0.6:
        print('D')
    else:
        print('F')
print('error grade out of range')
quit()
```

Comment: What makes you think you need a loop? You should try without it.

Comment: agred, the `range(0, 1)` is probably redundant

Comment: It's not clear what `for fg in range(0,1):` is supposed to do; you're completely overwriting and replacing `fg` with the integer value `0`. It seems that you don't know or understand what `range()` does.

Comment: Add some prints, do some debug. Your loop runs once and sets `fg` to 0 so the else always runs

Comment: @rv.kvetch what's the point of looping at all? It seems like only the `if` statement is needed

Comment: also probably you can remove the "error grade out of range". I not sure what is that doing.

Comment: Also you always print the error message... Did you actually mean `if fg in range(0, 1)`? That would still not do what you think it does...

Comment: As @MichaelM points out, you are assuming that `range()`  represents a segment of the real number line. It doesn't.  `range()`  gives you a bunch of integers, in this case a bunch of length 1 containing only the integer 0. Since `fg` is a float, it will only be in `range(0,1)` when it is exactly equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `range()` function. `range()` is used to iterate over multiple values, not to validate if a number is in a range. You should instead check that `fg` greater than or equal to 0, or less than or equal to 1. Like this:

```py
grade=input('Score Grade:')
fg=float(grade)

if 0 > fg or 1 < fg:
    print('error grade out of range')
    quit()

if fg >= 0.9:
    print('A')
elif fg>=0.8:
    print('B')
elif fg>=0.7:
    print('C')
elif fg>=0.6:
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')
```

Comment: or maybe: `if not 0 <= fg <= 1:`

Comment: *"`range()` is used to iterate over multiple values, not to validate if a number is in a range"* - depends what type of range. It wouldn't work in this case with floats, but you can totally do `if value in range(2, 6)` to check for natural numbers

Answer (score 0):

you are doing this for one time you dont need to use a loop
you can do this

```
grade = float(input('Score Grade:'))
if grade < 1 and grade > 0:
    if grade > 0.9:
        print('A')
    elif grade >= 0.8:
        print('B')
    elif grade >= 0.7:
        print('C')
    elif grade >= 0.6:
        print('D')
    elif grade < 0.6:
        print('F')
else:
    print('error grade out of range')
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use for operator neither range. The simplest solution is:

'''

grade = input("Enter number:")
try:
grade = float(grade)
except:
grade = -1

```
if grade >= 0.9:
    print("A")
elif grade >= 0.8:
    print("B")
elif grade >= 0.7:
    print("C")
elif grade >= 0.6:
    print("D")
elif grade < 0.6:
    print("F")
else:
    print("Error!")
    quit()
```

'''